# Call apply method with arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments, apply

I wanted to invoke a function using the javascript apply() method. This works fine if the function has no arguments. i.e.

```
function test()
{
  console.log(this);
}

body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; // shortcut to body element

test.apply(body); // returns [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

But I can't seem to do the same thing to invoke a function that has arguments:

```
function test(msg)
{
  console.log(msg);
}

body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; // shortcut to body element

test(this).apply(body); // mysteriously returns the correct result, then
// typeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating "test(this).apply".
```

The examples above are completely trivial but the grain of my question is: How do I use the apply() method to invoke a function with arguments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) takes two arguments:

```
test.apply(null, [body]);
```

The first argument sets the value of `this` when the function is executed. The second is an array of parameters for that function.

In your examples you could rewrite it as follows:

```
function test() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
test.apply(this);
```

Comment: Important to note that the second argument should be an array, rather than just a single element. `test.apply(null, body)` breaks for me (Chrome 35), but `test.apply(null, [body])` works.

Comment: What is the real use of using apply method is there any benefits?

Comment: I'm sure there are a whole host of real uses. Some that spring to mind are to monkey patch functions (including built-ins), for [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), and for specifying `this` for callback functions.

Comment: @JohnKeyes lets just say I have a function like `function test(msg){..}` & I need to set the this value & also want message value in `msg` only?
`test.call(newThisObj,'new this obj set');` value would be available in `arguments` instead of `msg`

Comment: @techie_28 you can use the following `test.apply(this, ['new this obj set']);`

Answer (score 8):

First notice that you are actually invoking your function immediately, the line:

```
test(this).apply(body);
```

Fails because at first, you call the `test` function passing `this` *as an argument*, and then you try to access an `apply` property on the function's result, which is `undefined` since your function doesn't return anything.

That property access on the `undefined` value is giving you the `TypeError` exception.

Now, let's see what you actually want to do, if you want to pass the value of the `body`  variable as the argument of your function, setting the outer `this` value, as the `this` value of `test`, you can do:

```
test.apply(this, [body]);
```

But that's why the `call` method exists, when you know exactly which arguments to pass, you don't need to create an array for nothing, you just pass the arguments:

```
test.call(this, body);
```

The `apply` method is really useful when you deal with for example a dynamic number of arguments, when you know which arguments want to pass, and still have the ability of setting the `this` value, `call` is just what you need.

Comment: Documentation for `call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 6):

With apply you send an array of arguments as its second argument:

```
test.apply(body,["Hello World"]);
```

Here is the apply documentation on the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @JohnKeyes is right, I should have paid more attention to my copy and paste.  I corrected the syntax error.

Comment: I'll delete my comments here if you like. They're not adding to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add in the argument:

```
test.apply(body, ["my message here"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

apply can take two arguments

1. An object to bind
2. An array of arguments to be passes to the method

   `test.apply(obj, arr);`

In this case the obj is body and arr is array of arguments.

Remember to accept the params in the invoked funtion as below

```
function test(...params)
 {
   console.log(this);
 }
```